# PDFStamper.close() throws IOException error

Tags: itext

We are trying to add a stamp to a 150mb file.  When the pdfstamper.close() is executed, we receive the following error:

2014-10-17 11:02:29,470 ERROR:  IOException: test.pdf not found as file or resource.>

```
**java.io.IOException:** test.pdf **not found as file or resource**.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:107)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:79)
```

When we look at the folder, the file has been removed and is replaced with a hidden file.  The hidden does not contain the stamp we placed on the pdf image.

Comment: I hope you use different file paths or names for source and destination files?

Comment: We have found a work around for this.  The file that we are trying to stamp is located on a mounted folder.  If we use a local folder, everything works appropriately. We are now copying the file from the mounted folder to a local folder.

Comment: Yes, we have different paths for the source and destination.